# SSL Certificate install on NGINX shows certificate invalid in browser

Tags: ssl, nginx

I received an SSL certificate from my client to install on his Ubuntu server.
The server is using NGINX as a web server and I have followed all required steps for this to happen, but the browser still shows the certificate as invalid.

This is what I did:

Edited my `sites-available` file:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        include snippets/iltlvdigitalit.conf;
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

        server_name iltlvdigitalit;
        root /var/www/html/digital-system/front-end/dist/digital;
        server_tokens off;
        index index.html index.htm;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /api/v1/ {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

iltlvdigitalit.conf

```
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/iltlvdigitalit.cert;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/iltlvdigitalit_new.key;
```

ssl-params.conf

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384;
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1; # Requires nginx >= 1.1.0
ssl_session_timeout  10m;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_tickets off; # Requires nginx >= 1.5.9
# ssl_stapling on; # Requires nginx >= 1.3.7
# ssl_stapling_verify on; # Requires nginx => 1.3.7
resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 5s;
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
```

[image: SSL Issue Chrome]
[image: SS: Issue Chrome]

Not sure what went wrong. Thanks! :)

Comment: Please enable browser warnings again and show the exact warning including the available details you get from the browser. These will provide the necessary detail on what is wrong. Typical reasons: issued by an untrusted CA or no subject alternative names.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thank you for the reply. What do you mean by enable browser warnings again? I tried the `chrome://flags/#mark-non-secure-as` flag in Chrome, but it doesn't show any warning in the console.

Comment: Please have a look at the images you have in your question. There is a dialog which clearly provides you with the option to re-enable warnings for the site.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Oh, sorry! I'm so stupid.. I've been fighting this SSL cert for so many hours I totally lost sight. Thanks a lot! will check.